# CredentialProvider not loaded in console session of Windows

Tags: session, server, console, windows-server-2016, credential-providers

I have a CredentialProvider created using the Windows template code for CredentialProvider, which is used to login user in Windows OS. It is working properly in most of the systems. But it is failing in a particular system, running Windows Server 2016 on Amazon Web Services(AWS), when running in console session. In same system, credentialprovider is working for RDP sessions. In other system running Windows Server 2016, CredentialProvider is working in all session(console and RDP).

Reason for it failing in this particular system is that my CredentialProvider is not loaded in console session, while it is properly loaded in RDP sessions. While in other system, where it is working, CredentialProvider is loaded properly in all sessions.

Can anybody please help me know possible reason for CredentialProvider not loaded in console session, and the way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and windows server 2016, there is change in architecture due to which in below cases Credential providers are loaded only after Legal Disclaimer is bypassed.

1. When policy of "Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL" is disabled which results in compulsion of pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL to get out of lock screen.
2. When lock screen is disabled. This can be configured following steps provided in https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-windows-10-lock-screen/.

In case if Legal Disclaimer is not configured, above issue is not faced.

In case of RDP(lock case), as legal disclaimer is not shown, it works well.